# StandardSetController (Edited)

Tags: apex, unit-test, visualforce-component, list-view, standardsetcontroller

I am trying to change a StandardConroller to StandardSetController in order to use list button with visualforce. I have updated to setSelected before b.sendemail(), however I now get "Variable setcon is used before it is declared".

The button will be used to send an email to each of the selected records in a list. I have a Visualforce page that will call the apex, but I need to make it accessible to "Choose" in the Visualforce listbutton option.

The class worked before for a custom non list button, but now I am trying to modify the code to apply for a custom list view visual force button.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Apex Class:

```
public class CustomButtonSendEmailListView {

    @testVisible private ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;

    public CustomButtonSendEmailListView(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        setCon = setCon;
    }

    public pageReference sendemail() {
        List<SalesstatementInvoice__c> sslist = (List<SalesstatementInvoice__c>) setCon.getSelected();
        SalesStatementInvoice__c salesStat = [Select Id, Name, Faktura__c, Contact__r.LastName, Contact__r.FirstName, Contact__r.Name, Afregningsdato__c, Show__r.Name, Account__c, Invoice_Number_E_conomic__c, Contact__c, Contact__r.Email, Valuta__c FROM SalesStatementInvoice__c where id =:sslist];
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        EmailTemplate SendPdfDK = [Select id, Body from EmailTemplate where Name = 'SalesInvoiceDK'];
        EmailTemplate SendPdfENG = [Select id, Body from EmailTemplate where Name = 'SalesInvoiceENG'];
        message.setTargetObjectId(salesStat.Contact__c);
        message.setwhatId(salesStat.Id);
        message.setSubject('FAKTURA ' + salesStat.Faktura__c + ' - ' + salesStat.Show__r.Name + ' - ' +
                salesStat.Afregningsdato__c.format());
        List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
        pageReference pdf;
        Currency__c curr = Currency__c.getInstance(salesStat.Valuta__c);
        if (curr != null && curr.Invoice_Language__c == 'Danish') {
            pdf = Page.SalesInvoicePDF;
            message.setplainTextBody(reOpenCaseTempBody(SendPdfDK.Body, salesStat));

        }
        else {
            pdf = Page.SalesInvoicePDFEng;
            message.setplainTextBody(reOpenCaseTempBody(SendPdfENG.Body, salesStat));
        }
        pdf.getParameters().put('id', salesStat.Id);
        pdf.getParameters().put('invNum', salesStat.Invoice_Number_E_conomic__c);
        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
        Blob body;
        if (Test.IsRunningTest())
        {
            body = Blob.valueOf('UNIT.TEST');
        }
        else
        {
            body = pdf.getContent();
        }
        attach.Body = body;
        attach.Name = salesStat.Name + '.pdf';
        attach.IsPrivate = false;
        attach.ParentId = salesStat.Id;
        Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
        efa.setFileName('FAKTURA ' + salesStat.Faktura__c + ' - ' + salesStat.Show__r.Name + ' - ' +
                salesStat.Afregningsdato__c.format() + '.pdf');
        efa.setBody(body);
        fileAttachments.add(efa);
        message.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{message});
        //insert attach;
        return new PageReference('/' + salesStat.Id);
    }

    public string reOpenCaseTempBody(string emailBody, SalesStatementInvoice__c s) {
        emailBody = emailBody.replaceAll('\\{!SalesStatementInvoice__c\\.Contact__r\\.FirstName\\}',
                String.valueOf(s.Contact__r.FirstName));

        return emailBody;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
global class CustomButtonSendEmailListViewTest
{

    @isTest static void SendEmailTestMethod() {

        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'Test Name';
        Insert acc;

        Contact con = new Contact();
        con.LastName = 'ContTest1';
        con.FirstName = 'ConFirstName';
        con.Email = 'test1contact@duptest.com';
        con.AccountId = acc.Id;
        Insert con;

        SalesStatementInvoice__c objSales = new SalesStatementInvoice__c ();
        objSales.Faktura__c = '513';
        objSales.Account__c = acc.Id ;
        objSales.Contact__c = con.Id ;
        objSales.Invoice_Number_E_conomic__c = '733';
        objSales.Valuta__c = 'DKK';
        insert objSales;

        System.currentPagereference().getParameters().put('id', objSales.id);

        Attachment objAtt = new Attachment();
        objAtt.Name = 'Test';
        objAtt.body = Blob.valueof('string');
        objAtt.ParentId = objSales.Id;
        insert objAtt;

        List<SalesstatementInvoice__c> sslist = [SELECT Id FROM SalesstatementInvoice__c LIMIT 1000];
        ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(sslist);
        CustomButtonSendEmailListView b = new CustomButtonSendEmailListView (setCon);
        b.setCon.setSelected(sslist);
        b.sendemail();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in `ApexPages.StandardController` but your constructor only accepts `ApexPages.StandardSetController`.  The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm) is pretty clear on how to construct this type.

```
List<SObject> records; // e.g. = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity LIMIT 100];
ApexPages.StandardSetController controller = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(records);
MyExtension extension = new MyExtension(controller);
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian.However I am still struggeling. I have just posted an edit: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97257/standardsetcontroller-edited

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getSelected()` in the first line of `sendEmail` but you never set any selected records try this:

change:

```
private ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;
```

to

```
@testVisible private ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;
```

Then before you call `b.sendEmail()` do this:

```
b.setCon.setSelected(sslist);
```

To set the selected records. Then when you do the getSelected in the first line it will have some records to work with

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have now made another edit, however it is still not working.. :/ I am fairly new to this so I appreciate very much your comments.

Comment: @mrtjj - Reread my post, you did not do it correct. You put the getSelected before the call in your test method not the setSelected(splits)

Comment: Thanks. Error went away but now I only get 5% coverage... What should I replace (splits) with? sslist? It still only return 5 % coverage. Updating an edit with the updated code now.

Comment: Yes...dang auto correct

Comment: and please mark the appropriate answer as correct so this question does not keep surfacing if it is answered. Do not keep editing to change the question. If you have a different question please start a new one

Comment: hehe :) However still not giving more than 5%.. am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry about the edit.. Still looking to find out what is wrong :/ appreciate the help alot though

Comment: Most likely. Look at what your code is doing / needs to do it and ensure you are setting up your test environment to provide what it needs. Review what lines are not covered and begin your logical deduction as to why they are not covered and fix it

Comment: Surprised your code is even compiling as this line should throw an error I believe: `SalesStatementInvoice__c salesStat = [Select Id, Name,Faktura__c,Contact__r.LastName,Contact__r.FirstName ,Contact__r.Name,Afregningsdato__c,Show__r.Name, Account__c,Invoice_Number_E_conomic__c,Contact__c,Contact__r.Email,Valuta__c FROM SalesStatementInvoice__c where id =:sslist];` since sslist is NOT an ID.

Comment: @Eric Doesn't it just essentially coerce `=` to `IN`? Agreed that these edits are getting out of hand.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - You are correct, learn something every day. Funny how this works but other things you think would "coerce" do not. Thanks for the comment......

Comment: @Eric It always seems to work that way when you have expectations about what Apex can/cannot do. What a weird language.